# Architecture, lots of methods vs long parameters lists

Tags: architecture, language-agnostic

We are trying to do things as clearly and cleanly as possible in a 3 tier architecture situation.

But the complexity of our system is leaving us confused about the best way to proceed.

If we use lots of chains of functions going through the service layer, with smaller parameter lists, this seems clear in terms of what is being done, yet it feels like a lot of functionality is being repeated across these methods.

However, if we use less methods, and have large lists of parameters to change functionality within the methods, this seems to get out of hand.

Our choice at the moment is have more functions as this feels easiest to manage than monolithic functions with lots of logic flows inside them. This obviously means smaller chunks of more manageable code.

It's just we hear about DRY a lot, so this feels like there is some repetition going on inside the methods. But it seems more flexible.

Comment: It's hard to respond to this question without a more concrete example of what you mean.

Comment: extract the repetition into a separate method?

Comment: It means we have the web tier, domain tier, and db tier. And DI is being used. So technically good practice, but has an overhead in terms of implementation. I feel it is relevant becuase the overhead means that we have to write more code to navigate through each of the tiers, which means the overhead between many functions or many paramaters is more strongly felt.

Comment: It might help if you could post an example (even if it is in pseudo code)...

Comment: would a data transfer object help, or does it just make the word soup worse? :o)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most people prefer smaller method signatures over large ones. It makes it easier to reason about the methods (not to mention test them!), however you shouldn't use this to justify violations of DRY principles.

Is there any reasons why you can't have small method signatures and factor out the common, replicated code into internal helper methods?

Comment: While the other answers here are great, this is the answer I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

I think it will be better to provide 2 examples of what do you mean.
It sounds like one of the following:

1. You have bad design.
2. You have interaction/behaviour spread out through many objects.
3. You are using DI\design pattern incorrectly.
4. Your code is actually procedural and not OO.

Because you didn't provide any example I will walk through only shortly for all of these options.

**1. You have bad design.**

**3. You are using DI\design pattern incorrectly.**

Maybe you should split out your code differently, maybe you should use DI or revisit of how you are using it. Maybe you should apply some design patterns to make the problem manageable.

**2. You have interaction/behaviour spread out through many objects.**
Consider to use of DCI http://alexsmail.blogspot.com/2012/09/dci.html to tackle this problem.

**4. Your code is actually procedural and not OO.**
I saw code wriitent in Java by the programmer that are regular to write procedural code. It has many parameters that *tweak* method execution. Solution will be to redesign your code and (re)train your programmers.

Comment: Thanks for the run down. Any of these options you have stated could be true. We will refactor as we go. But I think we will keep to many small functions in general.

Comment: When you say your code is procedural and not OO. What do you mean? Surely all OO code has some procedural code? We have DB objects, Domain Objects, ViewModels, Helper classes, Services, Interfaces, Repositories. Does that mean we have OO used enough?

Comment: From the description above-I don't think you have last problem. :-) All OO code has some procedural code. What I meant that I just saw procedural code written in Java, without Services, Interfaces, etc. :-)

Answer (score 1):

I really believe that for enterprise applications there's nothing better than a good layered architecture, with good intention revealing names for classes and methods, and some design patterns applied within the whole solution. 
Following this rule, it's contradictory to have long methods because probably they will be breaking the Single Responsability Principle, so they won't be expressing by their name what they are really doing. If you want to use the DRY principle just keep your methods and classes clean, short and clear and apply some design patterns to reuse them across the whole solution.

I recommend reading Domain Driven Desing (Eric Evans) and Clean Code (Robert C. Martin) to see more about this kind of "code phylosophy" in detail.

Answer (score 0):

I assume the "lots of methods" do the same function and the only that varies are the parameters.

My apporach would be to pass the data with a few objects, similar as how parameters are passed to a `GridBagLayout` in a `GridBagConstraints` objects. For example, for a search query I pass a bean "Filter" with all the possible conditions, the code in the method is lengtly but not complicated ("is condition X specified -> add X filter to query") and can be easily divided in a few helper functions.

Answer (score 0):

That is usually a symptom of strongly coupled applications. To get from A to B you have to take fifteen turns and then go back a bit.

A great way to reduce coupling is to introduce domain events. For instance, when a user is created you'll generate a domain event called `UserCreated` when is subscribed to by the class `SendWelcomeEmail` and `NotifyAdminsOfNewUser` or `SendIntroductionaryOffer`

The point is that anyone can act upon an event which effectively reduces complexity since you don't have to strongly couple your code anymore.